# Embedded Google calendar not displaying unless logged into Gmail or Google Account

Tags: iframe, calendar, google-calendar-api

I embedded my Google calendar using an iframe in the website but it seems I can only see the calendar when I am logged into a Google account. If I log out of my Gmail and then open the page, I just get an empty iframe.

accounts.google.com refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your calendar public in order to be able to see it without been logged:

- On a computer, open Google Calendar.
- At the top right, click Settings Settings and then Settings.
- Click the name of the calendar you want to share.
- Open Access permissions.
- Check the box next to "Make available to public".
- If you don't want other people to find the details of your events, select See only free/busy (Hide details).

On the [following link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083?hl=en) you'll find more info about calendar sharing: